# Safari 6 PDF Toolbar is not visible on hover

Tags: safari

We have a web application which displays a report in PDF format. We just embed the PDF into an iframe and everything works well.

However, when the same report is opened in Safari 6.0 it DOESNOT show the small toolbar(which specifies Download, Open in preview, Zoom In, Zoom Out options).

This toolbar is available in safari 6.0 if I right click --> Open PDF in New Tab --> go to the bottom of the page --> hover to the middle of the page.

The PDF viewer used in Safari 6.0 is "Webkit built in PDF".

My question is why does the toolbar appear when I opened the PDF document in a separate tab and not from within my application.(that is when its embedded inside an IFRAME)

More Information:
This is how the source elements looks like in IE 8:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="iframeReport" src="http://localhost/Report.aspx?DailySummary&PROCESSINGDATE=03%2f07%2f2013&rc%3aParameters=Collapsed&rc%3aJavaScript=False&rc%3aToolbar=True&rs%3aFormat=PDF&rc%3aArea=Report&rc%3aLinkTarget=_self&File=test.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>
```

This is how the source looks like in Safari:

```
<iframe id="iframeReport" height="100%" width="100%" style="height: 100%;  width: 100%;" src="http://localhost/Reports.aspx?DailySummary&amp;PROCESSINGDATE=03%2f07%2f2013&amp;rc%3aParameters=Collapsed&amp;rc%3aJavaScript=False&amp;rc%3aToolbar=True&amp;rs%3aFormat=PDF&amp;rc%3aArea=Report&amp;rc%3aLinkTarget=_self&amp;File=test.pdf">
#document
<html>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38)"><embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://localhost/Reports.aspx?DailySummary&amp;PROCESSINGDATE=03%2f07%2f2013&amp;rc%3aParameters=Collapsed&amp;rc%3aJavaScript=False&amp;rc%3aToolbar=True&amp;rs%3aFormat=PDF&amp;rc%3aArea=Report&amp;rc%3aLinkTarget=_self&amp;File=test.pdf" type="application/pdf">
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Safari, I've reported this to Apple a year ago, they are aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up installing Adobe Reader into the Mac machine. This way it doesn't use the built in PDF viewer.